# Toggle Available Input/Radio with JS

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a user input form that will disable/enable inputs depending on a prior input.

```js
var test = document.getElementById("type");
console.log(test.value);

if (test.value == 'Limited') {
  console.log('should be disabled');
  var radios = document.getElementById("disableme");
  for (var i = 0, iLen = radios.length; i < iLen; i++) {
    radios[i].disabled = true;
  }
}

function toggle() {
  if (test.value == 'Limited') {
    console.log('should be disabled');

    var radios = document.getElementById("disableme");
    for (var i = 0, iLen = radios.length; i < iLen; i++) {
      radios[i].disabled = true;
    }

  } else if (test.vlaue !== 'Limited') {
    console.log('should be enabled');
    var radios = document.getElementById("disableme");
    for (var i = 0, iLen = radios.length; i < iLen; i++) {
      radios[i].disabled = false;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<select id="type" name="type" placeholder="" style="width: 300px" onchange="toggle()">
  <option>Administrator
  <option>Elevated
  <option selected="selected">Limited
</select>
<form name="disableme" id="disableme">
  Alerts & Messages : Yes <input type="radio" name="alert" id="alert" value='1'> No <input type="radio" name="alert" id="alert" checked="checked" value='0'>
</form>
```

Here is what my page currently looks like upon load:
[image]

With the `limited` option selected, I want both radio buttons to be disabled and the `no` radio button checked. If the user selects `Administrator` or `Elevated` I want those radio buttons enabled. I have made it this far.

My only issue now is that when I switch back to limited, having checked the `yes` radio button, the yes will remain checked while the radio buttons are disabled.

You will see my radio buttons have the same name/id. This was done to prevent both being selected at the same time.

Comment: IDs **must** be unique

Comment: @j08691 thank you for your edit

Comment: The `name` attribute should be the same on both radio buttons; the `id`s must be unique to the element.. Use `var radios = document.querySelectorAll('#disableme input[type="radio"]');` in all of those places where you get the radio buttons and you should be set. If you want the No radio to be checked when limited is selected, set it to be checked. Within the loop where you're disabling them; `radio.checked = radio.value === '0';`.

Answer (score 0):

In your current code, `radios` always refers to a `form` element. While in your case the only elements in that form are the radio buttons, assuming that to be the case is risky. Someone else might come along and add a `button` and then your button starts getting disabled and everyone freaks out.

Instead, just target the radio buttons. In the code below, I've targeted them by `name`, since that is shared among the radio buttons I think you want to target.

(I should note that, semantically, all form elements (including `select` elements) should belong to a `form` in order to aid submission. If you're not submitting the form to a server, this is less of a constraint.)

In any case, I've simplified the code a bit to only require a single loop over the radio buttons; if the selected item is "Limited", it sets the radios to disabled, and sets the "No" item to checked. If the selected item is not "Limited" it enables the radios and leaves the checked state alone.

```js
var test = document.getElementById("type");

function toggle() {
  console.log(test.value);
  var radios = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="alert"]');
  for (var i = 0, iLen = radios.length; i < iLen; i++) {
    radios[i].disabled = test.value == 'Limited';
    if (test.value == 'Limited') {
      radios[i].checked = radios[i].value === '0';
    }
  }
}

toggle();
```

```html
<select id="type" name="type" placeholder="" style="width: 300px" onchange="toggle()">
  <option>Administrator</option>
  <option>Elevated</option>
  <option selected="selected">Limited</option>
</select>
<form name="disableme" id="disableme">
  Alerts & Messages : Yes <input type="radio" name="alert" id="alert" value='1'> No <input type="radio" name="alert" id="alert" checked="checked" value='0'>
</form>
```